# How to force Intellij to treat some random file other than registered type

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij Ide is choosing the wrong syntax highlighting. So I need to override preselected file type. File name can be anything, which means I need to change the file type on the fly.

Edit: There are no extention in the file name.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the extesion always the same?

Comment: I know that you can choose the "language" in a "Scratch File" (Tools > New Scratch File) but is it enough ? (it's only a scratch file : you have to copy/paste your code in it). Otherwise you can go to Settings > Editor > File Types and match your file extension to a File Type.

Comment: @dambros no extention is not same always